# Is vuetify v-select value not same on Created and onChange?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I defined a  like this:

```
<v-select item-text="name" item-value="value" :items="resource_items"
                    v-model="resource_item_selected"
                    prepend-icon="mdi-calendar-range"
                    @change="get_abc"
          >
```

and resource_item_selected is an JSON object like {name:'aaa', value:'bbb'}.
get_abc is a method in methods, and I try to use resource_item_selected in this method. When I separately call get_abc in 'Created' and '@change' , I find that resource_item_selected  is an object in Created but is a string in '@change', so I do not know how to use it ? Should I regard it as an object or string?

Comment: why do you want to use it in a created life cycle method ?

Comment: Because I want to initialize some value based on the resource_item_selected. And it is an object when I use it in created life cycle. When users change value of the resource_item_selected, it is a string in '@change' life cycle. And both Created and '@change' are calling a method in methods.

Comment: @Cheng show us get_abs and created part

Comment: once the user selected then you want the selected item then there is no need to use created .......use only methods to get the value on the @change ......created is used  only to do things at the time of render say example you want to add api calls then you can